# Printing OEmbed URL based on Post selected w/o page refresh

Tags: php, functions, oembed

The hardcoded HTML looks like this →

```
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/G4Q0oX8wquU" allow="autoplay; 
encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But in the case of the WordPress, it should come from the meta - The URL that is saved in Oembed.

Look at this image of the `single.php` backend →

[image]

I tried something of this sort:

```
<?php 
   $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_oembed', 1 ) ); 
   echo wp_oembed_get( $url );
?>
```

More precisely like this →

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php 
       $url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_oembed', 1 ) ); 
       echo wp_oembed_get( $url );
    ?>" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

But nothing actually worked. Please help me to understand the logical gap.

Extra Information →
Currently, a Loop is running that fetches posts that have video URL in the Oembed.

Loop is running like [this](https://www.screencast.com/t/nYAxYvKb).

The live page is [here](http://pen.blogeto.com/freelancer/hello-world-copy-copy/).

Currently, the Video is hardcoded, but the idea is as soon as one clicks on the image of the post thumbnail just below the hard-coded HTML video framework. the oEmbed Video URL should come with Iframe.
By default the Oemebed Video I frame should come of the latest post fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_oembed_get()` returns the whole iframe, that's its purpose. So you should use it on its own, not in the src of an iframe.

```
$url = esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'video_oembed', 1 ) ); 
echo wp_oembed_get( $url );
```

Comment: But I  think that this will work only in the WP Loop not outside the loop in single.php?

Comment: That’s got nothing to do with `wp_oembed_get()`. Only thing the loop would affect is how you get the meta value to use in it.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question.

Comment: `wp_oembed_get()` takes a URL and returns the oembed output for it. Typically an iframe. In terms of *getting* that URL from post meta? That's completely unrelated and depends entirely on how the field was originally added. Since WordPress does not have an oEmbed field in core you will need to consult the documentation for the theme/plugin that added the cutsom field for the URL.